# Union types with React Hook Form

Tags: typescript, react-hook-form

I have a component that should be able to be reused for 2 or more forms. I pass down the [setValue prop](https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform/setvalue#) method from react-form-hook down to the component. I've tried typing it with an union type `UseFormSetValue<FormAType | FormBType>`.

But this makes TS complain on one of the components that either properties are not present in the other object.

Reproduction repo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-meufv5?file=src%2FApp.tsx

Why is the union type not working like I would expect? Accept either A or B?

Is there a good workaround for this?

Comment: It seems to be a known issue :

https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/issues/9287

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to define a union type of **FormA** and **FormB** as **FormType**. The setValue function is explicitly cast to **UseFormSetValue** to match the updated FormType definition. This ensures that both FormA and FormB can be handled properly by the setValue function.

```
import Form from './Form';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { FormA, FormB } from './FormTypes';
import { UseFormSetValue } from 'react-hook-form/dist/types';

type FormType = FormA | FormB;
export default function App() {
  const { setValue } = useForm({
    defaultValues: { value: 'test' } as unknown as FormA,
  });

  return (
    <Form
      setValue={setValue as UseFormSetValue<FormType>}
      formObject={{ name: 'Jan', code: 10, key: 'string' }}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that solves the type error! I am wondering why it needs to be asserted as the complete union when passing the value in the component. Could you direct me to some documentation that explains this?